# ScriptableObject doesn't save list of System.Object types

Tags: c#, scriptable-object

```
    public class GameData : ScriptableObject
    {
        public List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
        public List<PostPrefab> prefabs = new List<PostPrefab>();
        public List<Thematic> thematics = new List<Thematic>();
        public List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        public List<object> test = new List<object>(); // doesn't saves after upd code
    }
```

Hello, help me pls, ScriptableObject doesn't save list of System.Object types.
I make changes through the UnityEditor but after updating the code, the list in the ScriptableObject is reset to the default value

everything except this list is saved..

i save changes in UnityEditor like this

```
        sobj.Update();
        if (GUI.changed)
        {
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(obj);
            sobj.ApplyModifiedProperties(); 
            EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
        }
```

I tried adding the [SerializeField] tag to the list, but that didn't help either..

Comment: System.Object is not serializable. You'll simply have to find a way around it. If you tell us why you want to serialize these objects, maybe I'll be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Verpous 
I have classes of types of awards, let's say Money, audience, new task.. and I want to save a list of these awards

Comment: If these classes inherit from some more specific Unity class like ScriptableObject, then you can turn your list into a list of that class. If they're [POCOs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object), you can create a class which unifies them all under one type, or create a separate list for each type.

Comment: Also worth reading about [SerializeReference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html), although I'm not sure I recommend its use.